# Nested API requests in a route node/express

Tags: javascript, api, express

I'm very new to coding and this is my first post here. My learning project is a website that uses an external CRM to store client data from web forms.

I have the storage part working fine, but can't figure out how to retrieve the data and pass it to a rendered page.
I need a route to do 3 operations, each operation works properly on it's own, I just can't figure out how to nest them so they happen in order.

1. Get details of a deal from the CRM

```js
var options = { method: 'GET',
                    url: 'https://crm.com/dev/api/opportunity/' + req.params.id,
                    headers: 
                        { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                         'content-type': 'application/json',
                          accept: 'application/json',
                          authorization: 'Basic xxx' },
                          json: true };
            request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) throw new Error(error);
                    return body.contact_ids;
            });
```

this will return an array of client numbers associated with the deal.

2. Iterate through the client numbers to look up data from each client, and put to array. I have defined an empty array called data, outside the function scope to catch the results.

   ```
        resultFromAboveRequest.forEach(function(id) {               
           var options = { method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://crm.com/dev/api/contacts/' + Number(id),
                headers: 
                 { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                    accept: 'application/json',
                    authorization: 'Basicxxx' },
                   json: true };

            request(options, function (error, response, body) {

               if (error) throw new Error(error);
               data.push(body);
           });
       });
   ```
3. render the resultant data array on a page

   `res.render("./applicants/resume", {data: data});`

I'm pretty sure this is a job for promises, however i just can't seem to get my head around the syntax. Any help would be appreciated and I apologise if the format of this question is amateurish or in some way inappropriate.

Comment: Please don't ever write `if (error) throw new Error(error);` inside an async callback.  It does nothing useful and can't be caught by any of your code.  You need to figure out how to actually handle your errors.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. I think I need to figure out a lot of things, but I have to start somewhere :-).  I'm so new at this I just copied and pasted the code from postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the `request-promise` library (which is a promise interface to the `request` library) and then using promises to manage the sequencing and error handling in a series of asynchronous operations.  You can do that like this:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://crm.com/dev/api/opportunity/' + req.params.id,
    headers: {
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        accept: 'application/json',
        authorization: 'Basic xxx'
    },
    json: true
};
rp(options).then(body => {
    return Promise.all(body.contact_ids.map(id => {
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://crm.com/dev/api/contacts/' + Number(id),
            headers: {
                'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                accept: 'application/json',
                authorization: 'Basicxxx'
            },
            json: true
        };
        return rp(options);
    }));
}).then(data => {
    res.render("./applicants/resume", {data: data})
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("internal server error");
});
```

Here's a general description of the steps:

1. Load the request-promise library.  Rather than taking a completion callback, it returns a promise that is resolved with the response body or rejected if there is an error.
2. Make the first request.
3. Use a `.then()` handler on the returned promise to get the result.
4. Process that result with `.map()`.
5. In the `.map()` callback, return another promise from a call to request-promise for each data item.  That means that `.map()` will return an array of promises.
6. Use `Promise.all()` on that array of promises to know when they are all done.
7. Return the promise from `Promise.all()` so that it is chained to the previous `.then()` handler for sequencing.
8. Then, in another `.then()` handler (which won't get called until both the previous operations are completely done), you will get the data from the `.map()` operation in proper order which you can use to call `res.render()`.
9. Finally, add a `.catch()` to catch any errors in the promise chain (all errors there will propagate to this `.catch()` where you can send an error response).